# A problem in divisibility #1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> $$2^{10^5} \equiv \ ? \pmod{77}$$

How to use the Chinese remainder theorem to compute the remainder? Or is there any other way (simpler?) without using CRT or Euler's theorem?

Comment: Use that $2^{30}\equiv 1\pmod {77}.$

Comment: CRT and Euler is (almost) always the easiest way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You ask for a method avoiding CRT. Here is one. Since $2^3\equiv 1\pmod{7}\,$ and $\,2^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}\,$ we deduce $\,2^{\color{#0a0}{30}}\equiv 1\pmod{77}.\,$ Applying the mod Distributive Law

$$10^5\bmod{\color{#0a0}{30}}\, =\, 10(10^4\bmod 3) = 10(1^4\bmod 3) = \color{#c00}{10}\ \Rightarrow\ 
 2^{10^5}\equiv 2^{\color{#c00}{10}}\equiv 23\!\!\pmod{\!77}$$

---

Below is a method using CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem

$\!\bmod{11}\!:\,\ 2^{10}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{10^5}\equiv (2^{10})^{10^4}\equiv 1^{10^4}\equiv \color{#0a0}1$

$\!\bmod 7\!:\quad\ 2^3\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{10^5}\equiv 2\ $ by $\, 10^5\equiv 1^5\equiv 1\pmod{\!3},\ $ so applying CRT

$\!\bmod 7\!:\ \ 2 \equiv x\equiv \color{#0a0}1\!+\!11\,\color{#c00}k\equiv 1\!+\!4k\iff 4k\equiv 1\equiv 8\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv2}$

Thus we have $\, x =  1\!+\!11(\color{#c00}2\!+\!7n) = 23 + 77n$

---

Answer (score 1):

$$ 
2^{{10}^5}\overset{7}{\equiv} 
2^{100000}\overset{7}{\equiv} 
2^{3 \times 33333+1}\overset{7}{\equiv} 
2^{3 \times 33333}2^1\overset{7}{\equiv} 
2^{3^{      33333}}2^1\overset{7}{\equiv} 
8^{      33333}2^1\overset{7}{\equiv} 
1^{      33333}2^1\overset{7}{\equiv} 
2 
$$

$$ 
2^{{10}^5}\overset{11}{\equiv} 
2^{100000}\overset{11}{\equiv} 
2^{10 \times 10000}\overset{11}{\equiv} 
2^{10 \times 10000}\overset{11}{\equiv} 
2^{10^{      10000}}\overset{11}{\equiv} 
1024^{      10000}\overset{11}{\equiv} 
1^{      10000}\overset{11}{\equiv} 
1 
$$

By chinese reminder theorem 
$ 
2^{{10}^5}\overset{77}{\equiv} 
2 \times (11 \times 2) + 1 \times (7 \times 8)\overset{77}{\equiv} 
44 + 56 \overset{77}{\equiv} 
23 
$.

Answer (score 0):

As  $77=7\cdot11$

$2^{11-1}\equiv1\pmod{11}\implies2^{10^5}=(2^{10})^{10^4}\equiv1^{10^4}=?\  \ \ \  (1)$

$2^3\equiv1\pmod7$  and $10\equiv1\pmod3\implies10^5\equiv1^5$

$\implies2^{10^5}\equiv2^1\pmod7\  \ \ \  (2)$

Now apply CRT on $(1),(2)$